# English translation of Xcode "Expected identifier" error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The line of code:

```
CGRect *bounding = [[NSAttributedString *initWithString:text]
    boundingRectWithSize:size
                 options:[[NSDictionary alloc]
        initWithObjectsAndKeys:kCTFontAttributeName, @"Scurlock 20", nil]
];
```

is getting an error of "Expected identifier" when I try to compile it. Earlier it didn't have "options:" but adding that in didn't change it.

I'm trying to get the bounding for the NSString variable named text, and would like to know what's wrong (presumably that I have mangled the syntax).

size is equal to CGSizeZero.

How can I correct this line of code so it says what I want?

--EDIT--

I'm getting the same error with this code:

```
-(float)getLength:(NSString *)text
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Scurlock" size:20];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGRect *bounding = [[NSAttributedString
            *initWithString:text] boundingRectWithSize:size
        options:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
            kCTFontAttributeName, @"Scurlock 20", nil]];
    return bounding->size.width;
}
```

My using CGFloatZero could have caused runtime flakiness and crashes, but I would expect something else to be the cause of a syntax error.

Is there anywhere I have missed an identifier that I should have put in the CGRect lines?

Thanks,

Comment: If you click on the error in the side bar, it'll show you exactly where in the line it found the problem — one of the improvements with LLVM over GCC is that errors are reported more precisely than merely to the line. In Xcode you should see a little caret below the line indicating the position. Where do you see the carets?

Comment: I moved to a different approach; I'd appreciate if you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963566/how-should-i-be-sending-a-message-with-a-field-of-the-same-object-as-its-value . I'm taking a different approach, and do not yet have pinned down why my attempt to create and access a method variable from within an object's implementation is off-syntax.

Comment: @JonathanHayward, by looking at this question and the other one you mentioned on your comment (for which I provided an answer too) I'd say you're not very familiar with the Objective-C syntax. Even if you moved to a different approach I believe the answer I provided for this question is the right one. Now, regarding your attempt to "create and access a method variable from within an object's implementation" I'd like to mention that in Objective-C it's not possible to access method variables from outside of the method scope.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is the asterisk before the `initWithString:` method.

```
[NSAttributedString *initWithString:text]
```

Unless I'm missing something, that asterisk shouldn't be there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Given that he's done the same thing in the code added by the edit, and is getting the same error, this would be convincing even without knowing Objective-C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`size` needs to be set to the maximum size allowable for the string.

For example if you want to know how tall the string would be with a max width of 320, you would do:

```
CGRect *bounding = [[NSAttributedString *initWithString:text]
    boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                 options:@{ kCTFontAttributeName : @"Scurlock 20" }];
```

If you don't care how wide the string could be, use `CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)`